# Local coefficients of vector fields are smooth

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $ M $ be a smooth manifold, and let $ X\colon M\to \mathrm TM $ be a vector field on $ M $.

If we pick a chart $ (U,\psi\colon U\to \underline U\subset \mathbb R^n) $ we can define a smooth local frame $ \partial_1,\dots,\partial_n\colon U\to \mathrm TM $ by
$$
\partial_j(p) = \Bigl(p,\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial\phi^j}\right|_p\Bigr)
$$
for every $ p\in U $, where $ \partial/\partial\phi^j|_p $ is the basis vector on $ \mathrm T_pM $ induced by the chart $ (U,\phi = (\phi^1,\dots,\phi^n)) $.

We can thus write
$$
X(p) = \sum_{j = 1}^n a^j(p)\partial_j(p)
$$
for $ p\in M $, where
$$
a^j(p) = X_p(\phi_p^j)
$$
is the $ j $-th coordinate of the vector $ X_p\in \mathrm T_pM $, where $ X(p) = (p,X_p) $.

I'm trying to show that the functions
$$
a^j\colon U\to \mathbb R
$$
are smooth, but I got lost in the formalism. Why are they smooth?

Comment: If you apply a smooth vector field (as a derivation) to a smooth function, you get a smooth function.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an outline:

A chart $(\psi, U)$ for $M$ induces a chart $(\tilde{\psi}, \pi^{-1}(U))$ for $TM$, where $\pi: TM \to M$ is the projection map. Express $X: M \to TM$ in local coordinates using these charts. The resulting map between Euclidean spaces is smooth since $X$ is smooth. In particular, the last $n$ coordinates will be smooth - use this to conclude that your $\alpha^j$ are smooth.

If this doesn't help, see propositions 3.18 and 8.1 in Lee's book on smooth manifolds.

Comment: Thank you so much, it was easier than I thought!

Comment: @GeometriaDifferenziale you're welcome!